# Edit shared file in several branches at once

Tags: git

How do I change a file and update all branches (because the file is the same for all).

I have a git repo for a dockerized application (prosody, but doesn't really matter). In this repo I have (for now) 2 branches: stable and nightly, which correspond to releases of prosody. Both repositories share the same `readme` file - usage of the docker container is the same, no matter if you want to use a nightly or stable version.

Now, I have found a typo in the `readme`.

As far as I understood, I have to create a branch to fix this typo and merge the change to both (all) branches. Is this the easiest way to do? Is this even correct?

Another solution might be to have a master branch containing only the `readme` and adding the `Dockerfile` to `.gitignore` in that branch. Then I do changes on master and rebase the other branches.

I'm asking because I can think of other cases as well - where there might be several branches which need to be updated (e.g. `.zshrc` containing some settings which should be the same on all machines and a branch for every system I'm using zsh on - one of them has docker, another one is used for android development or whatever)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a hotfix, you can use [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html), it allows you to pick a single commit and apply the diff patch to the branch you want it to be applied to.

For example let's say you created the hotfix directly on master, let's call the other branches you want to be updated: `a` and `b`

```
# current branch master just after the commit of the readme, let's say the
# abbreviation of your hash is abcdef

git checkout a
git cherry-pick abcdef

git checkout b
git cherry-pick abcdef
```